# Why we have to use quotation for c# code in java script (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Consider this code:

```
'@Url.Action("GetUsers","Cash")'
```

if use  with out quotation ,above code does work.

Why we should use quotation for c# code in java script ?

Comment: Where you see does not work

Comment: check yourself  without quotation will work or not. Don't ask this as a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass url to javascript variable - YES.
Because url is a string.

Try to not add quates for this and you recieve next line in javascript:

```
var test = /Cash/GetUsers;
```

javascript interpreter will say `SystaxError: Invalid regular expression` because only regular expressions in javascript can begin from `/` symbol.